# Lambda not invoking nodejs async pool connection

Tags: node.js, lambda, async-await, connection-pooling, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to understand why Lambda is invoking async pool connection and query with 2 minutes Eventbridge trigger, but not doing it with more than 10 minutes trigger? All this works locally, but not working on AWS lambda. There is no problem with VPC security etc. I have added `AWSLambdaExecute`, `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` and `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` Permissions as well.

```
'use strict';
const { google } = require("googleapis");
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.write = async event => {
  var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 1000,
    connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
  });

 const { sheets } = await authSheets();
  var query_outpayment_requests = queries()["outpayment_requests"];
  var datetime = "Last Sync: " + new Date().toLocaleString();

 await pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;

    connection.query(query_outpayment_requests.query, (error, rows) => {
      if (error) throw error;

      var values = [[datetime], Object.keys(query_outpayment_requests.mapping)]

      rows.forEach(row => {
        var row_values = [];

        Object.values(query_outpayment_requests.mapping).forEach((formatter) => {
          row_values.push(formatter(row));
        });

        values.push(row_values);
      });

      sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range: "SPR",
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
        resource: {values: values},
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error.');
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        }
      );


      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("SPR's processed");
    });

    connection.release();
  });
};

async function authSheets() {
  //Function for authentication object
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "keysfile.json",
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
  });

  //Create client instance for auth
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  //Instance of the Sheets API
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: authClient });

  return {
    auth,
    authClient,
    sheets,
  };
}
```

Comment: You mix callback style with async/await, that will not work as your expectation.

Comment: @hoangdv thanks for your answer! Whats your suggestions?

Comment: Select one style callback or async/await, I vote for async await.

Comment: you can use `mysql2` instead of `mysql`